# Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file: Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

i want to use following both in One page , please suggest me some solution

```
@model List<SelectListItem>Model
@model formData.Models.Employee 

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }
```

Comment: Use ViewModel have 2 of them

Comment: Use `ViewModel` for your purpose. You cannot call two `Models` inside a single `View`: https://rachelappel.com/2014/09/02/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use View Model like

```
    public class ViewModel  
    {  
        public  List<SelectListItem> SelectListItem{ get; set; }  
        public Employee  EmployeeDetails{ get; set; }  
    }
```

On View use like:

```
    @model ViewModel   
    @{  
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";  
     }
```